# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Lost Settings

Tags: 20.04

I buy new notebook 2-3 weeks ago. I download Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from official website
[https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop%60)

All been good but my pc freezes to die 3-4 times. And I lost settings. I can't find setting.

Here

[image: Here]

lost settings and in menu I can't find that.Please help and Thanks to all.

I can't reinstall Ubuntu.
Here I wrote many scripts and hardly install and configure MySQL...

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center` try this command..

Comment: Thanks. That Work...